# worldfootballR Package; Error: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

Working with worldfootballR package and having trouble scraping data from some urls. If you go to the [github](https://jaseziv.github.io/worldfootballR/articles/extract-transfermarkt-data.html#expiring-contracts), you'll see examples using country name and league url without any issue. I'm able to run all of these without any issue. However:

```
library(worldfootballR)
#Using country name
argentina_expiring <- tm_expiring_contracts(country_name = "Argentina", 
contract_end_year = 2023)
#Using league url
argentina_expiring <- tm_expiring_contracts(country_name = "",
contract_end_year = 2023,
league_url = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/superliga/startseite/wettbewerb/AR1N")
```

Using either of these for this league (and several others) results in:

```
Error: subscript out of bounds
```

No dataframe is pulled and I'm unsure how to work around this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since this package-specific, consider posting an [issue](https://github.com/JaseZiv/worldfootballR/issues) on the repo for authors.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though there are no expiring contracts for both the Argentine and Brazilian first division leagues:

[Argentine Expiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFKYH.png)

But there is for the EPL:

[EPL Expiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WE06.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).